# Antonyms of "no such thing as"

Tags: vocabulary

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there-s-no-such-thing-person-as)

> there's no such thing/person (as): used to say that something or someone does not exist

> I've told you before, sweetie, there's no such thing as ghosts!

I understand the meaning and the usage of it.

Does the expression "no such thing as" have any antonyms?

In other words, does such an expression exist to convey the idea that something might exist?

---

I [googled it](https://www.google.com/search?q=opposite%20of%20%22no%20such%20thing%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=opposite%20of%20%22no%20such%20thing%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.4854j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but got nothing.

I tried ["is there anything as"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20there%20anything%20as%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) and the top hits are something like `as adjective as ...`

I also searched on [the Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-such-thing#:%7E:text=phrase,exist%20or%20is%20not%20possible.) and [wordhippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/no+such+thing.html) but didn't find an answer yet.

[Searching for "such a thing" on google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22there%20such%20a%20thing%20as%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) gets about 185,000 hits while the Merriam-Webster dictionary doesn't include it, which probably means it is not established yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching, I got:

> **very much so**

This is an antonym as before you are denying the extistence of the thing but here you are very much areeging with it.

Answer (score 2):

It's usual to say "there is such a thing as", when affirming that something exists. For example: "There's such a thing as a zebra, but there is no such thing as a unicorn."

Answer (score 0):

> Does the expression "no such thing as" have any antonyms?

There is such a thing as...